# What is Context in NestJs

Tags: nestjs

I'm new to nestjs, I'm studying nestjs from its [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/).

I see the word **context** a lot in the documentation.
For example:

```
Execution Context
Application Context 
Http Context
```

I want to know what "Context" means.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: More information at this URL specifically: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context#execution-context

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation regarding [Execution context](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context#execution-context):

> Nest provides several utility classes that help make it easy to write applications that function across multiple **application contexts (e.g., Nest HTTP server-based, microservices and WebSockets application contexts)**. These utilities provide information about the current execution context which can be used to build generic guards, filters, and interceptors that can work across a broad set of controllers, methods, and execution contexts.

If I translate properly, in NestJS, the context corresponds to the way you mount your NestJS application; like HTTP, RPC for microservices, WebSocket, but could also be just a [standalone app](https://docs.nestjs.com/standalone-applications) (i.e. *without any network listeners*).